# SQL Server 2008 - is the name "Procedures" reserved?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, I named a table "Procedures"

Whenever I write a query, the word Procedures changes to green, but none of my other table names do.  I imagine this has something to do with Stored Procedures, which has nothing to do with the table I created.

Am I OK to use the table name Procedures, or should I change it?

Comment: when in doubt expand the name to be more specific, like `WidgetProcedures` or `AccountingProcedures`, etc. [cluttering] your [code] with [braces] is far [worse!]

Answer (score 5):

`Procedures` turns to green because it is the name of a catalog view, `sys.procedures`. When I see an item that clashes with T-SQL color coding (whether reserved or not, and whether it causes errors today or not), I question whether that is the best name to use.

If I move to a new version of SQL Server and a word has suddenly become a keyword or reserved word, there is little that can be done except for either (a) a full and painful refactoring or (b) using square brackets around the name to make sure SQL Server understands it's an identifier. This won't turn green, for example:

```
SELECT cols FROM dbo.[Procedures];
```

It's not as pretty obviously, but in addition to not lighting up green, it actually insulates you from future compatibility issues should they ever make `procedures` a keyword or reserved word.

In general, I find it safer to use square brackets around any identifier names that are even in the realm of possibility of ever becoming a keyword.

Comment: Interesting to know why it actually turns green.  +1 from me.

Comment: Delimiting the name only prevents it from turning green, it doesn't change the name itself. Try `SELECT * FROM [sys].[procedures]`, it will return the same as `SELECT * FROM sys.procedures`.

Comment: Who said it changed the name itself?

Comment: Well, no-one did, but if any of the system catalog names, like `procedures`, `tables`, `objects` etc., becomes a reserved word, you'll have to delimit it when referencing the corresponding catalog, thus preventing your interactive tool from highlighting it in green, which defeats the object of recognising the name as a special one in the first place. So, to me, a green name actually indicates that the corresponding word will unlikely become reserved too soon.

Comment: Okay. I was just using that as an example because that's what was in the question. I'd follow the same rule for any word that highlights in any color - for example, `description` lights up in blue, but it is not a reserved word. Still I think it is safer to enclose it as `[description]` both to prevent the blue from making it *seem* like a keyword and to prevent issues should it ever become a first class keyword in the future. Probably unlikely but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be OK.  "Procedure" (singular) is a reserved word, but "Procedures" (plural) is not.

Here is a list of all the reserved keywords - [SQL Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Note that you are allowed to name a table whatever you want.  I wouldn't consider it best practice to name a table as a reserved keyword, but you can.  Be aware that you will have to modify your queries slightly if you do this, by wrapping the table name in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your table anything you want (except it has to follow rule of [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) and cannot be more than 128 characters long). If it happens to be a reserved word you will have to use [TableName]. It is generally not advisable to do so though. It could confuse other developer and may cause problems in future upgrades if it becomes a reserved keyword.

Procedures is not a reserved keyword while Procedure is.

[Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)